# How to filter and map an observable?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am trying to *filter* and *map* an observable for an accordion list. Now I have a command toggleitem(index) that will open an item of the list:

```
toggleitem(index){
    this.retar[index].open= !this.retar[index].open;
    if (this.automaticClose && this.retar[index].open){
      this.retar
      .filter((item, itemIndex) => itemIndex !== index)
      .map(item => item.open =false);
    }
}
```

That used to work for me when I was working with an array -
now that I started working with observables it started giving me errors
so I tried this:

```
toggleitem(index){
    this.retar[index].open= !this.retar[index].open;
    if (this.automaticClose && this.retar[index].open){
      this.retar.pipe(
      filter((item, itemIndex) => itemIndex !== index)).pipe(
      map(item => item.open =false));
    }
  }
```

Now open gives me this error:

> Property open does not exist on type retar[]

Any help is appreciated.
**retard.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>retard</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-card>
    <ion-text>
      Justifiee:  <br>
      Non Justifiee: <br>
      Total: <br>
    </ion-text>
  </ion-card>
  <ion-list-header>
    <ion-label>List Header</ion-label>
  </ion-list-header>
  <ion-list *ngFor="let item of retar; let i = index;" class="accordion-list" lines="none" detail="false" no-padding>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label tappable (click)="toggleitem(i)" [ngClass]="{'section-active': item.open, 'section': !item.open}">
        {{item.Date}} {{item.Debut_Heur}}-{{item.Fin_Heur}}
      </ion-label>
    </ion-item>

    <div *ngIf="item.open">
      Type: {{item.Type}} <br>
      Matiere: {{item.Matieres}} <br>
      Justification: {{item.Justification}} <br>
      Duree: {{item.Duree}}
    </div>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

**retard.page.ts**

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/dot-notation */
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RetardService } from './retard.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Retard } from '../models/retard';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/internal/operators/filter';
import { map } from 'rxjs/internal/operators/map';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-retard',
  templateUrl: './retard.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./retard.page.scss'],
})
export class RetardPage implements OnInit {
  retar: Observable<Retard[]>;

  automaticClose = false;

  constructor(private retardService: RetardService) {
    this.retar = this.retardService.getRetard();
  }

  toggleitem(index){
    this.retar[index].open= !this.retar[index].open;
    if (this.automaticClose && this.retar[index].open){
      this.retar.pipe(
      filter((item, itemIndex) => itemIndex !== index)).pipe(
      map(item => item.open =false));
    }
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**Retard.service.ts**

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { retry, catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RetardService {
  private baseUrl = 'http://localhost/tpangularmysql/gestiPersonne.php';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getRetard(): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}?operation=listeEtudiantsRetardsJSON`).pipe(
      map(res => res["data"])

    );
}
}
```

Comment: you are unsing an observable object, i'm not seeing when did you subscribe to it

Answer (score 1):

pay attention to the different between map function of js, and the map function of rxjs
js map - use on array like this `yourArray.map(item => item.open =false))`

rxjs map - use inside pipe function and it's giving you the entire array that is the value of the observable so if you want to map the array you should do it like this:

```
pipe(
 // rxjs map
 map(items => { 
       // js map
       return items.map(item => item.open == false)  }))
```